# Delete query using jsps

Tags: html, sql, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm new to JEE programming, I know that the way I present you my problem is not optimal but I have to do it using only JPSs first.

So, I created a form that included checkboxes. I would like to delete all members that have been checked. My tag action form redirects to dispaly.jsp where I perform delete query before redirecting to my main page, members.jsp.

The problem is that my server crash and does not redirect me. I have to restart it, But my rows have been deleted in my database.

Here's my code :

```
<form method="post" action="display.jsp"><table id="members_table">
        <tr>
            <th>Sel</th><th>FIRSTNAME</th><th>NAME</th><th>EMAIL</th>
        </tr>
        <%
            while (resultset.next()) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="<%=resultset.getString(1)%>"/></td>
            <td><%= resultset.getString(2)%></td>
            <td><%= resultset.getString(3)%></td>
            <td><%= resultset.getString(4)%></td>
        </tr>
        <%}%>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Details" name="details" id="details_members">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete" id="delete_members">
    </form>
```

display.jsp page :

```
RequestDispatcher requestDisp = request.getRequestDispatcher("/members.jsp");
    if(request.getParameter("delete") != null)
    {
        if(request.getParameter("selected")!=null)
        {
            String[] a = request.getParameterValues("selected");

                str = "DELETE FROM MEMBERS WHERE ID = ";
                for(int it=0;it<a.length;++it)
                {
                    if(it==a.length-1)
                        str+=a[it];
                    else
                        str+=a[it]+" OR ID = ";
                }

            statement.executeUpdate(str);

            requestDisp.forward(request, response);
        }

        requestDisp.forward(request, response);
    }
```

When I run my code, I get this error after a long time waiting :

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Unable to get a lock within the requested timeout

root cause

> java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Unable to get a lock within the requested timeout

I don't understand why my server crash, I tried to execute this delete query directly in my database and it works. I also debug my code to see if my variable "str" contains right query ...

Please help.